# How to set ssl_verify_client per location in nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, client-certificates

I would like to set the ssl_verify_client nginx config value on a per location basis. This appears to not be supported yet:

http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/317

Is there any other workaround that people are using?

The motivation for wanting to do this is to create an API that is protected by TLS's mutual authentication; however, this same HTTPS port will be used by a standard web browser where, for deployment complexity reasons, will not be expected to have a client certificate. In addition, nginx is reverse proxying our WebSockets and turning on ssl_verify_client there breaks WebSockets on most web browsers I've tried.

Comment: As far as I searched, it is (still) not possible and it is technically a bit complex because it requires a secure TLS renegociation. However I just see TLS 1.3 plans to remove renegociation, so it would also remove this per-location feature if I’m not mistaken.(I’m also interested in such a feature.)

Comment: What if you make another server with a different host name inside the same http context? You can use the same HTTPS port, as long as the server_name directive is different nginx will allow multiple servers. Something like `server_name = "clientsecure.example.org"` for the host that will have ssl_verify_client. Not sure if this will work but the docs seem to indicate it will.

Comment: @GVH I don't believe you can use the same HTTPS port (even with a different `server_name`), unless you bind to two different IP addresses (so no virtual hosts)